# Node RED on Docker writing on MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, node-red

I am running Node-RED on Docker, and I am trying to write data to MySQL on my localhost.

As host, I am using localhost (see picture)

[image: Node-Red Host]

I receive the error: `connection refused`.

Which Host address should I use here? I don't quite understand the communication between the container and the local host.

Comment: Do you mean the database is not in the Docker VM?

Comment: Database is not on Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` always points to the TCP/IP stack that the program opening the connection is bound to.

Every Docker container has it's own TCP/IP stack so unless the database is running in the same container as Node-RED `localhost` will not be the correct hostname for the database.

You have 3 choices

1. If you are using docker-compose then you can use the container name as the hostname and it will connect to the right container.
2. You can use the `docker inspect [container-instance-name]` to find the IP address assigned to the database container and use that
3. If you have mapped the container port to your host machine (with the `-p` option) then you can use the IP address of the host which normally defaults to `172.17.0.1`

Edit:

To connect to the host machine then you can use `host.docker.internal` on Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac (unfortunately the [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264) to fix this on Linux has been open for over 3 years).

You should also be able to use the IP address from point 3 above.

Comment: Just for clarification: MySQL is not running on docker, just Node-RED. Are your solutions still valid? Thank you very much!